# Need help Piping Python twitter script to NLP Bash script (Sed, grep etc....)

Tags: python, twitter, stream, pipe, nlp

**Hello, I'm very new to programming and I've started only a few weeks ago. It would be greatly appreciated if I could get some help. Thanks in advance !**

1. My python script (stream_tweets.py) streams 200 - 300 tweets from twitter per minute. The script is located in '/home/computer/Twitter/examples/stream_tweets.py'
2. I have an NLP (Natural Language Processing) bash script that analyzes sentences and prints it out on bash. The NLP script (corenlp.sh) is located in '/home/computer/Standford/corenlp.sh'
3. If I create a new bash script, how do I pipe the tweets into the NLP? How would this script look like?
4. My python tweet script (stream_tweets.py) needs to output the text in utf-8 format, how do I change the script to do so.
5. The NLP takes a while to load, If tweets are storming into the NLP which hasn't loaded yet, will it affect my script? If so what can I do and how to do it?
6. **Take a look at the stream_twitter.py script**

   ```
    from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
    TRACK_TERM = ‘keyword1,keyword2,keyword3'
    CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY,
                     CONSUMER_SECRET,
                     ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
                     ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    r = api.request('statuses/filter', {'track': TRACK_TERM})
    for item in r:
        print(item['text'] if 'text' in item else item)
   ```
7. **Take a look at the NLP script**

   ```
    OS=`uname`
    # Macs (BSD) don't support readlink -e
    if [ "$OS" == "Darwin" ]; then
        scriptdir=`dirname $0`
    else
        scriptpath=$(readlink -e "$0") || scriptpath=$0
        scriptdir=$(dirname "$scriptpath")
    fi
    echo java -mx3g -cp \"$scriptdir/*\"            edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP $*
    java -mx3g -cp "$scriptdir/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP $*
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pipe output form one command as input to another command on a Linux shell like this:

```
$ program_a | program_b
```

So in your case this would look like this:

```
$ python /home/computer/Twitter/examples/stream_tweets.py | /home/computer/Standford/corenlp.sh
```

But in order to make this work, you might need to change `corenlp.sh` so that the last command that invokes the java StanfordCoreNLP program, reads input from the pipe (/dev/stdin) in this case. So change the last line to:

```
java -mx3g -cp "$scriptdir/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP $* < /dev/stdin
```

In order to make your python script print UTF-8 encoded strings, you need to change your python script in the end to:

```
import sys
for item in r:
    text = item['text'] if 'text' in item else item
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(text.encode('utf-8'))
    sys.stdout.buffer.write('\n')
```

I don't think it will be a problem when the Java program requires some time to start, I think the python script will be blocked writing until the pipe buffer is emptied.

Comment: You simply use the full path to the script. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Please upvote or accept the answer if this a solution to your problem :)

Comment: Oh Sorry, Bernhard, I was trying it out. Your pretty smart, i was on your profile and I was trying to give you a good rating but I couldn't find it anywhere ! Thank you a million times xoxo

Comment: It says I can't vote the question up because I need more reputation :(